# Google Bigtable under usage "performance"

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have seen the warnings of not using Google Big Table for small data sets.

Does this mean that a workload of 100 QPS could run slower (total time; not per query) than a workload of 8000 QPS?

I understand that 100 QPS is going to be incredibly inefficient on BigTable; but could it be as drastic as 100 inserts takes 15 seconds to complete; where-as a 8000 inserts could run in 1 second?

Just looking for a "in theory; from time to time; yes" vs "probably relatively unlikely" type answer to be a rough guide for how I structure my performance test cycles.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit. It seems to be talking about 2 separate things: data set size and QPS. Bigtable is not recommended for small data sets because it splits the data into multiple tablets and distributes those tablets across multiple servers. This allows it to support high QPS by load balancing across those servers. If your dataset is small, it can't be split across multiple servers and will hotspot a single server.

Comment: My question is about both those points. So will the single hot-spotting server still be able to serve in order of 10000 QPS on the small data set that it owns?

Comment: Assuming no contention between the keys, it should be fine. Also, please note that to achieve a high throughput for write you have to use bulk requests (ie. BufferedMutator in java or ApplyBulk in the golang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a flat start up cost to running any Cloud Bigtable operations.  That start up cost generally is generally less than 1 second.  I would expect 100 operations should take less than 8000 operations.  When I see extreme slowness, I usually suspect network latency or some other unique condition.

Answer (score 0):

We're having issues with running small workloads on our Developer Big Table instance (2.5 TB) One instance instead of 3.

We have a key set up on user id and around 100 rows on the key user id.  Total records in the database are a few million.  We querying big table and seeing 1.4 seconds of latency from fetching the rows associated with a single key of user id.  Total number of records returned is less than 100 and we're seeing way over a second of latency.  It seems to me that giant workloads are the only way to use this data store.  We're looking at other NoSQL alternatives like Redis.